# Splitting a string to find data contained within it

Tags: python

I am trying to write a rota script for my team.

The rota just alternates between 3 names.

The output is in wiki markup

Therefore the lines look like this:

```
| 17-09-14 | <name> | <phone num.> |
```

(names and numbers removed for confidentiality)

What I want my script to do is to read the last line of the file and find out the name, then decide the next name based on that one.

eg.

```
if name == 'john':
    new_name = 'bob'
elif name == 'bob':
    new_name = 'tom'
elif name == 'tom':
    new_name = 'john'
```

But I can't work out how to get the name part of the line. I could probably split the string but I'm struggling to get that to work.

Comment: Use an array to store the names instead, it's cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will always have your string formatted in this manner, you can `split` on the pipes, then grab the `[2]` element.

```
s = '| 17-09-14 | bob | 123-456-7899 |'

>>> s.split('|')[2].strip()
'bob'

>>> s.split('|')[2].strip() == 'bob'
True
```

Comment: You were just a bit faster than me ;)